Generate timestamp series between given dates
Given min and max dates are:
Min date: 2023-06-19 09:54:23.000
Max date: now()::timestamp(0)-interval '1 year'
Expected output:
start_date                      end_date
-------------------------------------------
2023-12-01 00:00:00.000     2023-12-09 23:59:59.999
2023-11-01 00:00:00.000     2023-11-30 23:59:59.999
2023-10-01 00:00:00.000     2023-10-31 23:59:59.999
2023-09-01 00:00:00.000     2023-09-30 23:59:59.999
2023-08-01 00:00:00.000     2023-08-31 23:59:59.999
2023-07-01 00:00:00.000     2023-07-31 23:59:59.999
2023-06-01 00:00:00.000     2023-06-30 23:59:59.999

My try:
with cte 
as 
(
    SELECT days 
    from generate_series('2023-06-19 09:54:23.000',now()::timestamp(0)-interval '1 year',  '1 month') days 
    order by days desc
)
select date_trunc('MONTH', days::date)::timestamp(0) start_date, 
       (date_trunc('month',  days::date)::timestamp(0) + interval '1 month -1 millisecond') end_date
from cte;

Following is missing date from above query result.
start_date                      end_date
--------------------------------------------------
2023-12-01 00:00:00.000     2023-12-09 23:59:59.999

Why I need this date entry? - I want the current date - 1 year date entry with start date of the month ONLY for the first entry.
The current - 1 year date should be end date and its month start date should be start date of the serires.
If the current date is 2024-12-22 then output should be:
start_date                      end_date
--------------------------------------------------
2023-12-01 00:00:00.000     2023-12-22 23:59:59.999

If the current date is 2024-01-01 then output should be:
start_date                      end_date
--------------------------------------------------
2023-01-01 00:00:00.000     2023-01-01 23:59:59.999



If the min_date is 2023-06-19 09:54:23.000 why does the first interval start with 2023-06-01 00:00:00.000? 2) The issue is you are changing expectations within the query, going from full months to partial months and the terms you use don't make it clear what those expectations are.


@AdrianKlaver, There is a constraint only for the max_date. The min_date is anyway minimum date value from the table for which there is no constraints at all.

@AdrianKlaver, I think I got it, used this for end_date calculation `case when (date_trunc('month',  days::date)::timestamp(0) + interval '1 month -1 millisecond')

now()::timestamp(0)-interval '1 year' then now()::timestamp(0)-interval '1 year'
else (date_trunc('month',  days::date)::timestamp(0) + interval '1 month -1 millisecond')
end as end_date`


Widen your generate_series() range and use least() to switch your final date:
demo at db<>fiddle
select days::timestamp(0) AS start_date
      ,least( current_date+interval '-1 year +1 day -1ms'
             ,date_trunc('month',  days)::timestamp(0)
              + interval '1 month -1 ms') AS end_date
from generate_series( date_trunc('month','2023-06-19 09:54:23.000'::date)
                     ,current_date-interval '12 months'
                     ,'1 month') AS days
order by start_date desc;




start_date
end_date




2023-12-01 00:00:00
2023-12-09 23:59:59.999


2023-11-01 00:00:00
2023-11-30 23:59:59.999


2023-10-01 00:00:00
2023-10-31 23:59:59.999


2023-09-01 00:00:00
2023-09-30 23:59:59.999


2023-08-01 00:00:00
2023-08-31 23:59:59.999


2023-07-01 00:00:00
2023-07-31 23:59:59.999


2023-06-01 00:00:00
2023-06-30 23:59:59.999



Use order by only in the outer query, otherwise Postgres doesn't guarantee it'll follow the order of subqueries and CTEs.

I don't think this works for current_date '2024-12-20' and after

@Thaw Thanks for catching it and pointing that out. Right now I just tested that and you're right. I'll try to take a look into it later

@Thaw Looks good now if you care to take a look.

You need to change only the intervall and remove one month see examples, to get the complete set of moth,
Adding a send cte to grab the last Month, which you need to differentitiate beween the last month and the rest
With cte as  (    SELECT days 
    from generate_series('2023-03-19 09:54:23.000'
      ,now()::timestamp(0)-interval '1 year  -1 Month',  '1 month') days 
    order by days desc)
  , MAXmonth as (
  SELECT
  MAX(date_part('month', days)) max_month
  FROM CTE)
select date_trunc('month', days) start_date ,
  CASE WHEN max_month = date_part('month', days) 
  THEN 
  CURRENT_DATE 
     + 
    MAKE_INTERVAL(YEARS := EXTRACT(YEAR FROM days)::INTEGER - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)::INTEGER 
   )
   + TIME '23:59:59.999'
  ELSE
  (date_trunc('month',  days::date)::timestamp(0) + interval '1 month -1 millisecond') END
  end_date
  FROM cte CROSS JOIN MAXmonth




start_date
end_date




2023-12-01 00:00:00
2023-12-09 23:59:59.999


2023-11-01 00:00:00
2023-11-30 23:59:59.999


2023-10-01 00:00:00
2023-10-31 23:59:59.999


2023-09-01 00:00:00
2023-09-30 23:59:59.999


2023-08-01 00:00:00
2023-08-31 23:59:59.999


2023-07-01 00:00:00
2023-07-31 23:59:59.999


2023-06-01 00:00:00
2023-06-30 23:59:59.999


2023-05-01 00:00:00
2023-05-31 23:59:59.999


2023-04-01 00:00:00
2023-04-30 23:59:59.999


2023-03-01 00:00:00
2023-03-31 23:59:59.999




SELECT 10


fiddle

Please check the expected result 2023-12-01 00:00:00.000     2023-12-09 23:59:59.999, I want end date should be 2023-12-09 23:59:59.999 NOT 2023-12-31 23:59:59.999

i chnaged the query so that it fits your wanted result for thos month but if your current month is not december you need soem more calculations for te new rule set

your result is 2025, not 2023

yes i had only a typo in the code

now try setting the start date to '2021-03-19 09:54:23.000'. you logic is applied every december

Depending upon your intended usage you may want to generate tsrange (timestamp range) instead of separate dates. (see demo)
with cte(days) as 
     ( select *  
         from generate_series( date_trunc('month','2023-06-30 09:54:23.000'::timestamp)
                             , current_date-interval '1 year' 
                             ,'1 month'
                             ) 
     ) -- select * from cte
select tsrange(days::timestamp(0) 
            , least ((days+interval '1 month ')::timestamp(0)
                    , (current_date-interval '1 year - 1 day')::timestamp(0)
                    )       
            ,'[)')  start_end_dates
  from cte
 order by days desc;




start_end_dates




["2023-12-01 00:00:00","2023-12-10 00:00:00")


["2023-11-01 00:00:00","2023-12-01 00:00:00")


["2023-10-01 00:00:00","2023-11-01 00:00:00")


["2023-09-01 00:00:00","2023-10-01 00:00:00")


["2023-08-01 00:00:00","2023-09-01 00:00:00")


["2023-07-01 00:00:00","2023-08-01 00:00:00")


["2023-06-01 00:00:00","2023-07-01 00:00:00")



NOTE on RANGES: Ranges can include or exclude either range begin or range end. The above creates the tsrange to include the range begin and to exclude the range end. When values are read keep in mind that for range end this means up to but not including that value. Therefore the first line above means all times starting at "2023-12-01 00:00:00" up to but not including "2023-12-10 00:00:00"  
NOTE on demo: Demo shows range ending 1 additional day from the indicated expected values. This is due it being run in UTC time zone as that is the setting on db<>fiddle server. (It's located in the UK). Where the date had already changed to 2024-12-10.
